# why the maven spring web MVC error version

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using maven : spring webmvc version 6.0.4 .But when I use a bean :
"". to upload the file, it gives an error.
but when I remove version 6.0.4 instead version : "spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE" it gives no error. but my website is not working.

this is the error when I add the bean to "webmvc version 6.0.4":
this is my file xml:
[image]
this is my servlet.xml:
[image]

this is when i remove "webmvc version 6.0.4" and add "spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE" version:
this is my file xml:
[image]
After adding, the bean file does not report any more errors:
[image]
but the website is not working anymore:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, edit your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: You cannot use Spring 5 or earlier with Tomcat 10. If you want to use Tomcat 10, you have to use Spring 6. If you want to use older Spring versions, you have to use Tomcat 9 or even earlier (Spring 3 is ancient, and you really shouldn't be using it these days).